# OnClickListener and CheckBox Errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm relatively new to app development and very confused about what to do here. Please be very clear and very detailed in your responses, much appreciated!

I'm getting a host of errors from the following code block:

```
//Blank out the appropriate blanks
    chkRect.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (chkRect.isChecked()){
            chkCyl.setEnabled(false);
            txtDiameter.setText("0");
            txtDiameter.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else {
            chkRect.setEnabled(true);
            txtDiameter.setText("");
            txtDiameter.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }});

    chkCyl.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (chkCyl.isChecked()){
            chkRect.setEnabled(false);
            txtHeight.setText("0");
            txtWidth.setText("0");
            txtHeight.setEnabled(false);
            txtWidth.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else {
            chkRect.setEnabled(true);
            txtHeight.setText("");
            txtWidth.setText("");
            txtHeight.setEnabled(true);
            txtWidth.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }});
```

On both "onClickListener" lines and the 'public void' lines, the following shows up:
-onClickListener cannot be resolved as a type. (multiple lines)
-Method setOnClickListener(View.onClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments new onClickListener. 
-The Method "onClick(View v)" must override or implement a supertype method.

Here are my imports and variable declarations:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;



public class MaterialCalculator extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

public Spinner materialDD;
public CheckBox chkRect;
public CheckBox chkCyl;
//public Spinner shapeDD;
DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("#");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_material_calculator);

    materialDD = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.materialDD);
    final CheckBox chkRect = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkRect);
    final CheckBox chkCyl = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkCyl);
    //shapeDD = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.shapeDD);
    Button btnCalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
    Button btnClearAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClearAll);
    final EditText txtDiameter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDiameter);
    final EditText txtLength = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLength);
    final EditText txtWidth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtWidth);
    final EditText txtHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtHeight);
    final EditText edtTxtTotprice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTxtTotprice);
    final EditText edtTxtWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTxtWeight);
```

I tried other solutions on this problem, including deleting the imports for view and onClickListener and using the ctrl+shift+O import, but it didn't work. Like I said, please be very specific with your answers since this is my first app and I'm not at all familiar with Eclipse to any great extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
chkCyl.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){
```

with

```
chkCyl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
```

and

```
chkRect.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){
```

with

```
chkRect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
```

`setOnClickListener` takes as paramter an instance of a class that implements the `OnClickListener` interface

Comment: Oh wow. All that work and it was capitalized...

Thank you so much, you are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can't get the variable from within the saved instance state? Try to define the variable right before the onClick Listener like this:

```html
final CheckBox chkRect = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkRect);

chkRect.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (chkRect.isChecked()){
            chkCyl.setEnabled(false);
            txtDiameter.setText("0");
            txtDiameter.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else {
            chkRect.setEnabled(true);
            txtDiameter.setText("");
            txtDiameter.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }});

    final CheckBox chkCyl = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkCyl);
    chkCyl.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){
        @Override`enter code here`
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (chkCyl.isChecked()){
                chkRect.setEnabled(false);
                txtHeight.setText("0");
                txtWidth.setText("0");
                txtHeight.setEnabled(false);
                txtWidth.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else {
                chkRect.setEnabled(true);
                txtHeight.setText("");
                txtWidth.setText("");
                txtHeight.setEnabled(true);
                txtWidth.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }});
```